# Is it possible to save Auditlogs from Kafka headers to MongoDB sink without using HeaderToField SMT?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

My incoming Kafka messages contain Auditlogs in the Kafka headers. How can I save the Header value to my MongoDB sink?

Note:

1. Shouldn't use HeaderToField SMT as our connector is not having that SMT.
2. No new SMTs

Comment: Connectors don't "have SMTs". Workers do. How do you know HeaderToField is not available?

Comment: While creating connector in confluent cloud it is showing few smts.. their HeaderToFeild SMT not present.

Comment: You could use ksql to move headers to the value in a new topic before writing connect config

Comment: Can we use AVRO value-format with Headers?

Comment: Headers are always bytes. Serialization format shouldn't matter

Comment: Feel free to post your working solution below

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM `streamName` (`topicname` BYTES HEADER('\''__connect.errors.topic'\''),`errormessage` BYTES HEADER('\''__connect.errors.exception.message'\''), `exception` BYTES HEADER('\''__connect.errors.exception.stacktrace'\'')) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = '\''topicname'\'', VALUE_FORMAT = '\''JSON'\'');

Comment: Please use answers section below, not a comment

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM 
streamName (topicname BYTES HEADER('\''__connect.errors.topic'\''),
errormessage BYTES HEADER('\''__connect.errors.exception.message'\''),
exception BYTES HEADER('\''__connect.errors.exception.stacktrace'\'')) 
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = '\''topicname'\'', VALUE_FORMAT = '\''JSON'\'');
```